# Number of ggplot option as argument of function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with this function here:

```
library(ggplot2)
getp1 <- function(names, data, colors) {
  num_lines <- length(names)
  p1_colors <- colors
  names(p1_colors) <- names
  p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,720)), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[1]], geom="line", aes(colour=names[1]), size=1) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[2]], geom="line", aes(colour=names[2])) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[3]], geom="line", aes(colour=names[3])) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[4]], geom="line", aes(colour=names[4])) +
    scale_x_continuous(name="") + scale_y_continuous(name="") +
    scale_colour_manual(name = "", guide = FALSE, values = p1_colors)
  return(p1)
}
```

Right now, I get four data lines from this. But I want it to plot exactly `num_lines` lines, so I guess I need to find some way to "copy" the `stat_function()` bit `num_lines` times. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Please give an example of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Completely fail to see the purpose of this and may have misunderstood the question. But I think that you can just use `lapply` to achieve what you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
# your version, changed so it works for me... 
# (may already be something else than you expected?)
getp1_old <- function(names, data, colors) {
  p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,720)), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[1]], geom="line", colour=colors[1], size=1) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[2]], geom="line", colour=colors[2]) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[3]], geom="line", colour=colors[3]) +
    stat_function(fun=data[[4]], geom="line", colour=colors[4]) +
    scale_x_continuous(name="") + scale_y_continuous(name="") +
    scale_colour_manual(guide = FALSE, values = colors)
  return(p1)
}
# my version, with lapply
getp1_new <- function(names, data, colors) {
  num_lines <- length(names)
  stat_fct_combine <- lapply(1:num_lines, function(index){
    stat_function(fun=data[[index]], geom="line", colour=colors[index]) 
  })
  p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,720)), aes(x)) + 
    stat_fct_combine +
    scale_x_continuous(name="") + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="") +
    scale_colour_manual(guide = FALSE, values = colors)
  return(p1)
}
# reproducible example
nms <- paste0('nr', 1:6)
dta <- list(function(x) 1, function(x) 2, function(x) 3, function(x) 4, 
            function(x) 5, function(x) 6)
cols <- rep(c('red', 'green', 'black', 'blue'), length=6)
# example plots
getp1_old(nms, dta, cols)
getp1_new(nms[1:4], dta, cols)
getp1_new(nms, dta, cols)
```